# SQL TSQL Query to get the count of equipment on weekly basis

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, sql-server-2008-r2, helper

```
ID | Equipment   |  HireDate    |  HireTodate   | ActualOffhireDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
01 | Printer     |  01/01/2013  |   31/12/2016  |
02 | Printer     |  01/05/2015  |   31/12/2016  |
03 | Laptop      |  17/01/2016  |   31/12/2016  |
04 | Laptop      |  01/01/2015  |   31/12/2016  |  28/01/2016
```

I have like the above table and would like to get the count based on weekly (from friday to thurday) for month of january 2016 as per the below

```
Equipment |  January count  | Week 1| Week 2| Week 3| Week 4
------------------------------------------------------------------
Printer   |   02            |  02   |  02   |  02   |  02
Laptop    |   02            |  01   |  01   |  02   |  01
```

Comment: Saturday to Friday, or Friday to Thursday perhaps?

Comment: I am unable to get the count of the weekly using the between condition

Comment: What SQL have you tried?

Comment: you need to have calendar table ,please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a calendar table which helps in processing this kind of queries very fast and with minimal effort.

Here is one way  which i used to generate [calendar](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/) table..and it looks like below in my environment...

[image]

Once you have calendar table,all you have to do is join date which you want to count which is as simple as below

```
select 
equipment,
count(*) as 'Jancount',
sum(case when wkno =1 then 1 else 0 end) 'Week 1',
sum(case when wkno =2 then 1 else 0 end) 'Week 2',
sum(case when wkno =3 then 1 else 0 end) 'Week 3',
sum(case when wkno =4 then 1 else 0 end) 'Week 4'
from
calendar c
join testtable p
on p.hiretodate=c.date
group by equipment
```

**Output:**
[image]